# Give in date with PHP, get data with SQL

Tags: php, mysql, date, mysqli, bind-variables

Currently I have a database with each row having a date. In PHP I want to make a input box where the user can input a date (for example 2014/05/11). This will be sent to the sql query to receive the values of that day.

I am using MySQL.

Now I have implemented the date input field, it sends date through but SQL doesn't understand what I try to do.

How do I make a date from php understood by sql?

Now I have like:

```
$date = "2014-05-11";
```

SQL being:

```
$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM " . TBL_MEMBERS . " WHERE DATE=$date ORDER BY $order LIMIT :startRow, :numRows";
```

But that doesn't seem to work.
Any tips/idea's on what I should try next?

Comment: 5.5.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 is the version, and ok Gary, will check.

Comment: I don't want to put in a date to the DB I want to receive the information where DATE=$date

Comment: got it, still should be using bind variables but i'll toss up an answer that helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE DATE=? ORDER BY ORDEBRYCOLUMN LIMIT ?, ?");
$date = "2014-05-11";
$stmt->bind_param('sii', $date, 0, 30);
$stmt->execute();
```

Bind params protect you from SQL injection attacks. If you put a variable directly into a SQL server string, someone can add more SQL to that string variable and run more sql queries than you want them to.